# Remove text before = character in notepad++

Tags: regex, text, replace, notepad++

First the text looked like this:

```
Ab Yz=15,Cd Wx=2,Ef Tu=20,...
```

I replaced all `,` with `\r\n`, so the text looked like this:

```
Ab Yz=15
Cd Wx=2
Ef Tu=20
```

Than I wanted only the numbers after the `=` and replaced `^.+[=]` with "blank" and my result was just `20`
Does Notepad++ think, that the whole document only has a single line and takes the last `=` and deletes everything before that?
How can I fix this? Oh and how can I remove the text after the `=`? (including =)

Edit: I also tried `^.+[\=]`, `^.+(=)` and `^.+(\=)` but I got the same result.

Comment: Uncheck `. matches newline` option

Comment: @revo yepp that worked, thanks!

Comment: @revo would you like to make that an answer, so I can accept it? Otherwise more answers will come in, I suppose.

Comment: @Selphiron You should add that detail to the question (the one that you have the *`.` matches newline* option on). Perhaps, add a screenshot with the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have unintentionally checked <kbd>. matches newline</kbd> option which makes a `.` in a regex to go beyond a line - it will match newlines as well (AKA DOTALL modifier). So you should uncheck it.

Also there is no need to do this job in two separate steps. Use regex `[^=]+=(\d+),?` and replace with `\1\n`

This will turn such an input string:

```
Ab Yz=15,Cd Wx=2,Ef Tu=20,Ef Tu=20,Ef Tu=20,Ef Tu=20,Ab Yz=15,Cd Wx=2,Ef Tu=20,Ef Tu=20,
```

To:

```
15
2
20
20
20
20
15
2
20
20
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **Regular expressions** in the left-bottom side of **Replace** window and find `([A-Z]+) ([A-Z]+)=` replace with empty string.

More info [here](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I already got this part :) 
I wanted to get the numbers after the `=`

Comment: To much coffee I guess :)

Comment: @Selphiron Hey! Have you tried my *brand new* answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

To change all in one pass, you could do:

- Find what: `(?:^|,)[^=]+=([^,]+)(?:,|$)`
- Replace with: `$1\r\n`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: It doesn't work properly unless you change non-capturing groups to positive lookaheads and substitute replacement string with `$1\n`.

Comment: @revo: True for line break I've missed, but there"re no needs for lookahead.

Comment: @revo: Did you try it in Npp?

Comment: It seems that notepad `Replace All` functionality is not a real `Replace All` but a normal single `Replace` function that is fallen in a loop. That is why it works. Normally it shouldn't.

Comment: @revo:Yes, you're right. But this is working for OP.

Comment: Then, there you go.